# Sublime doesn't want to open hidden folders

Tags: sublimetext2, finder

I am a new user of Sublime Text.
Today, i have written my first snippet and when i tried to save him, Sublime sent me to my user folder. Then i tried to find 'library' folder but Sublime didn't see it. 
I tried opened "Packages" folder from fast save(arrow down near "Save as", then second line, "where") but it didn't open.
Finder sees all folder, include hidden of course.
Any suggestions on how to identify/fix the problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you press shift+command+g in the save dialog then type ~/Library, does it show the folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you create and save a snippet, ST2's default is to prompt you to save it in your `User` folder, that is

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User`, not your `home` directory, which seems to the the crux of your problem.

Either save your snippet in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User`, or create a snippet folder within, i.e.

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/my_snippets`

By default, ST2 **shows** hidden directories.  The only directories that are hidden by default are

`folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"]`

Comment: It is difficult to explain, so i have recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEKi48FR2Cw)